# Are restrictions in iOS by device and not iCloud account?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Just getting to grips with restrictions on multiple iOS devices using the same AppleID. Are restrictions device specific? If yes, do I have to set them up again on the other device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Restrictions are limited in scope to the device on which they are configured. If more than one device is tied to the same Apple ID, restrictions will have to be set up separately.